# Symfony2: update query with query builder

Tags: symfony

This is my query

$id contains primary key and $status contains new status

```
public function updateStatus($id,$status)
{
    $qb=$this->createQueryBuilder('b')
             ->update()
             ->set('b.status',$status)
             ->where('b.id='.$id);
    echo $qb;
    return $qb->getQuery()
              ->getResult();
}
```

Problem I am facing is

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 56 near 'Complete WHERE': Error: 'Complete' is not defined.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing "Complete" make sure it is passed as String. Pass it as $var = "'Complete'"